# Unresolved Inclusions in Eclipse-Cygwin- #include <stdio.h>

Tags: c, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have been trying to test a program using cygwin64 (on Windows 10 and Eclipse 20-21) because my target is a Linux Realtime system, I have installed cygwin64 and as per this document (https://www.eclipse.org/4diac/documentation/html/installation/cygwin.html) . I have to add environment in windows

[image: Cygwin path in environment pic]

still my inclusion `#include<stdio.h>`, `#include <stdlib.h>` etc says unresolved

[image: unresolved inclusion pic]

I checked if Cygwin is installed by going to cmd and giving  bash. which returned correctly

My path variables are like this

[image: Path variables pics]

My toolchain settings are like this

[image: Tool chain pic]

This is my build report

```
15:52:34 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project udpexx1 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\cygwin64" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\udpexx1.o" "..\\src\\udpexx1.c" 
Cannot run program "gcc": Launching failed

Error: Program "gcc" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\cygwin64\bin]


15:52:34 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 94ms)
#####################################################################
```

Is there anything that im missing or need to do?

my run configurations are like this

[image: Run configuration pic]

Comment: There is no Eclipse 20-21.

Comment: Sorry , its eclipse 2021-03

Comment: have you installed the gcc compiler and the cygwin header files as cygwin packages ? https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.what-packages